# Can I have a data-pipeline as a part of my cloud-formation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-data-pipeline

My app has a `S3` bucket with daily feeds, 2 `DynamoDB` tables that stores this data, an `ELB` application that exposes the JSON API to that data and a `data pipeline` flow that processes the incoming data and uploads into the tables.

My `CloudFormation` template currently builds the tables and the ELB app. I'd want the pipeline flow to be a part of the template too (so a complete staging environment, for example, will be built together).

I couldn't find references for that in the manuals. Does anyone know how to do it or can confirm that it's officially not supported?

Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing my previous answer as Cloudformation has been supporting Data Pipeline.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-datapipeline-pipeline.html

As @SmartFingers noted, Data Pipeline is offered in fewer regions (although AWS has been adding) than Cloudformation itself.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/02/20/aws-data-pipeline-now-available-in-four-new-regions/

Comment: that's what I was afraid of.. so if I need to create the pipeline based on output values from my template (dynamodb tables names for example), I'll have to create the template, get the values, amend the pipeline JSON file and activate it?

Comment: Yes.  That is the only approach I know of.

Comment: CloudFormation supports Data Pipeline since June 11, 2015: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html

Comment: Another issue is, Data pipeline is only supported in x-large regions. CFN doesn't support resource creation from a different region.

Comment: Can nested stacks be used as defined here ? 
 I did not get a chance.  curious.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/multiple-account-multiple-region-aws-cloudformation/